# Google Places API - can I save place_id?

Tags: google-places-api

We develop a platform for building travel itineraries.
The travel plan (=trip) is combined of places ordered by a user defined flow.
We want to use Google Places API for searching places. We would like to store a place_id, and use it  for retrieving a trip info. The place_id will be used for fetching that place details from Google.
A place_id will be saved for future use only if a user decided to include that place within his trip itinerary.

Is it permitted according to the terms of use ?

Thanks!
Orit

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes you can

> Place IDs are exempt from the caching restrictions stated in Section 10.1.3 of the Google Maps APIs Terms of Service. You can therefore store place ID values indefinitely.

[Referencing a Place with a Place ID](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places#placeid)

Answer (score 6):

I am currently asking the exact same question to myself.

Reading throught the Google Places API documentation (as you also did I guess), I haven't found a clear/explicit answer to that question.

However,  several parts of the documentation make me think that **place_id** can be saved and used later on to retrieve a place result.

In the "[Place Details Results](https://developers.google.com/places/documentation/details?hl=fr#PlaceDetailsResults)" section, it is said that the **"id"** property is deprecated and should be replaced by place_id.  As "id" was said to be a **stable identifier**, I conclude that place_id is also a stable identifier.

Another interesting part is the one about the "**alt_ids**": it is said that a given place can see its place_id changing over the time: when the SCOPE changes, a new place_id is attributed to this place. So, I would said that:

- a place_id is unique and stable for a given place and a given SCOPE (APP|GOOGLE), **as long as the place exists**.
- a given place will remain searchable using any the place_id  previously attributed to this place
- using an APP scope place_id, there is no guaranty that the result sent in the response has the same place_id (it is not a problem, but it need to be kept in my mind, from a developing point of view)

At the end, unfortunately, I have no definitive answer. It is just my current assumptions. I hope somebody will help us with that question.

Regards

Philippe